# Power consumption of Android app programatically at Runtime

Tags: android, performance, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am building an Android application and would like to be able to dynamically optimize its power usage by increasing/decreasing Bluetooth Low Energy scan period. The problem comes from the fact that different handsets use different BLE chips resulting in different power consumption for those (e.g. Samsung S6, S7 use way more energy when BLE scan is running that most other phones).

What I want to do is be able to measure the impact of BLE scan on the battery life and adjust the scan period accordingly so that I could sacrifice some performance but gain in battery life by lowering scanning period.

The only solution that comes to my mind now is monitoring phone's battery level when the screen is off and adjusting scan period accordingly, but such an approach would be biased by other apps consuming much energy.

Question is the following: how can I programatically check app's (or specifically BLE peripheral's) impact on the battery? If I am able to do that, then the rest of the logic is just a piece of cake.

Thanks in advance!